# Android framelayout inflate not connected to java file

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that I inflate using the following method. The layout shows up but the problem is the java file for the fragment is not connected and it doesn't do any of the methods.

```
final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameSet);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){


                public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View v, int position, long id){
                    frame.removeAllViews();
                    switch (position){
                        //
                        //Your tab titles
                        //
                        case 0:
                            LayoutInflater.from(Activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_emp_remove, frame, true);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            LayoutInflater.from(Activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_email_change, frame, true);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            LayoutInflater.from(Activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_schedule, frame, true);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            LayoutInflater.from(Activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_pin, frame, true);
                            break;
                        default:
                    }

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Which methods do not work? Are they related to the layouts?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create fragments dynamically by using only the fragment layouts. Instead create a fragment instance and replace it to the frame layout with a fragment transaction.

```
EmpRemoveFragment fragment = EmpRemoveFragment()
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frameSet, fragment)
    .commit()
```